# Type of Direction

Tags: film-techniques, cinematography

What do you call a type of direction(?) where the perspective changes from one character to another?

I couldn't make the story shorter. Please, bare with it.

Ex:

Characters: 
- Deliveryman
- Woman
- Husband

The deliveryman delivers food to the woman's house. As he knocks, he notices the door is open so he sneaks into the house, he then finds out the woman is lying dead. As the deliveryman sees the woman's condition, he proceeds to inspect the weapon used against the woman, as he was about to get ahold of the weapon, the woman's husband arrives. The husband, in shock, locks the door and calls for the police as the deliveryman tries to beg, "No, no, no. This is not my doing, you got it all wrong!" to the husband. The police arrives and captures the deliveryman.

As the deliveryman is being captured, the scene stops, everything restarts and the story is retold prior to the supposed assassination of the woman. The whole scenario is repeated as how it was before the accident but the perspective is shifted to another one of the characters.

Answer (score 4):

Generally, a multiple-perspective narrative is referred to as “*Rashomon*-style” after [the 1950 movie of that name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rashomon).